# i don't want to use std::copy...his this the right for-loop alternative?

Tags: c++, stl

i'm trying to not use STL. i have this line in my code:

```
std::copy(buffer_, buffer_ + size_ + 1, new_buffer)
```

if i want to NOT use copy, is this the right equivalent?

```
for (int i = 0; i < (size_ + 1); i++){
    new_buffer[i] = buffer[i];
}
```

or is that totally wrong? or is it off by one? or something else?

thanks!

Comment: Why are you trying not to use the standard library?

Comment: I really wish no one would have responded until AFTER you answer @GMan's question...

Answer (score 5):

Okay, the two code-samples you have will give the same result.

However, you will have an off-by-one error if you use `size_ + 1`. Just `size_` is the correct value since it already points to one past the last element.

Comment: What do you mean? The size of the buffer is `size_ + 1` in both versions. There's no error.

Comment: I'm just pointing out that he probably meant the size of the buffer to be `size_`. I've seen some people get confused by the "one past the end" to (mistakenly) throw in a `+1`.

Comment: @Kerrek: Mysticial is correct, `i < (size_ + 1)` will iterate one past the end. Same with the `std::copy` version.

Comment: Well, we don't know what `size_` is. Maybe there's a null-terminated thing going on. The question is only whether the two constructions are equivalent. I guess we could warn the OP to check the construction, though, just to be sure.

Comment: @Kerrek: True, it could be a string. The OP should clarify this.

Comment: @Kerrek: Right, my bad. Though, fidgeting with null-terminated `char*` strings is sure the wrong thing to do in C++...

Comment: @Xeo: I semi-frequenly copy `str.c_str(), str.c_str() + str.length() + 1` when using C APIs like `iconv` or `mbstowcs`... it's certainly not an unheard-of situation.

Comment: @Kerrek: I'm happy I don't have to do that. :) Though, it should be `c_str()` *or* `data()`. ;)

Comment: @Xeo: That's what I said, isn't it ;-) How would *you* use `iconv`?

Comment: @Mysticial: Strictly speaking, `size_` doesn't "point" anywhere, as it's just a number. On the other hand, `buffer_ + size_` points to the element preceded by `size_` elements (which may or may not be "one past").

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear whether what you wrote works. The `copy` version works if `buffer_` is *any* random-access and `new_buffer` is *any* output iterator. Your manual version only works if `buffer_` is a pointer.

Other than that, your manual version is functionally equivalent. If the types are POD, though, you could probably do better with `memcpy` (subject to checking for overlaps).

Note that your buffer, the way you wrote it, has size `size_ + 1`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it, since it's easier to reuse with general iterators (much like std::copy), because the code that is specific to the iterator type (random access) is outside of the loop:

```
buffer_type* begin = buffer; // EDIT: buffer_type is whatever type buffer contains.
buffer_type* end = buffer + size + 1; // EDIT: usually this would be 'buffer + size'
buffer_type* out = new_buffer; // EDIT: don't want to lose the pointer to new_buffer!

while(buffer != end) {
  *out = *begin
  ++begin; ++new_buffer;
}
```

So you wouldn't have to change the loop if you decided to use some other type of iterator.

Some code checking utilities might complain about this because they think you are going to incur an access violation, but that's not the case since the last dereference happens before the last incrementing.

The choice of `size` for a variable name is kind of confusing here, BTW.  It implies that `buffer + size` would be one past the end of `buffer`, since you start labeling elements of an array at zero, but you start counting them at one, so the last element will be at index `size - 1` typically.

Also, if you are going to use a for loop and the indexing operator you should use an `unsigned int` to index.  Negative indices are legal, but I don't think you intend to allow them here.